# Convert win_service_info dictionary to lowercase

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am using the `win_service_info` module to store the services of a Windows machine into a dictionary. But, later, I want to search for a specific service by the path to the executable. I want this to be a case insensitive match because part of the path variable is going to be entered in by a user.

I have tried tons of stuff: `map`, `combine`, etc. But, it always fails because my `set_fact` always seems to set my variable type as something other than a dictionary (a list, a string, etc.).

I just want to do a simple lowercase to lowercase comparison to find a match to the executable path in the list of services.

```yaml
- name: Getting services...
  ansible.windows.win_service_info:
  register: services

- name: Converting to lowercase...
  set_fact:
    lower_services: "{{ services | lower }}"

- name: Locating service by installation path...
  set_fact:
    target_service: "{{ lower_services |
                        selectattr('path', 'equalto', SchedulerPath | lower) |
                        first }}"

  when: lower_services |
        selectattr('path', 'equalto', SchedulerPath | lower) |
        list | length > 0
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `win_service_info` module output? Do I understand correctly, you like to have all dictionary keys in lower case?

Comment: From what I gather in the [`win_service_info` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_info_module.html#return-services), you do not gather a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Preferably what I need is the values to be lowercase. If your executable path in the registered service is C:\Program Files\Application\application.exe and the user types in c:\program files\Application\application.exe...when I use selectattr and use this user generated path to find find the value in the path key that I want, I won't find it because of the differences in case.

So however it happens, that value in the path key in my services list of dictionaries (Thank you for the correction) needs to be lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jinja [`match` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/match_test.html) along with its parameter [`ignorecase`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/match_test.html#parameter-ignorecase) in order to make case insensitive search.

But, since you are now making a regex search, you will have to escape the regex tokens out of your search string. This can be achieved with the [`regex_escape` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_escape_filter.html#).

So, your `set_fact` ends up being something like:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    target_service: >-
      {{
        services.services
          | selectattr(
            'path',
            'match',
            SchedulerPath | regex_escape ~ '$',
            ignorecase=True
          )
      }}
```

---

For example, given:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    target_service: >-
      {{
        services.services
          | selectattr(
            'path',
            'match',
            SchedulerPath | regex_escape ~ '$',
            ignorecase=True
          )
      }}
  vars:
    SchedulerPath: c:\windows\system32\foo.exe
    services:
      services:
        - name: foo
          path: C:\Windows\system32\FOO.exe
        - name: bar
          path: C:\Windows\system32\BAR.exe
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    target_service:
    - name: foo
      path: C:\Windows\system32\FOO.exe
```

*<sup>Note: the above output was generated running the playbook with the option `-v`, which, amongst other useful information, shows the result of a `set_fact` task.</sup>*

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for! Thank you! I will checkout -v as I was trying to do that with debug. -v would make things much easier to debug!

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Given the dictionary `d1` search items from the list `test` case insensitive."***

```yaml
  test: [key_A, kEY_b, key_x]
  d1:
    key_a: 1
    KEY_B: 2
    kEy_C: 3
```

A: Update lowercase keys

```yaml
  d2: "{{ dict(d1.keys()|map('lower')|
               zip(d1.values())) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  d2:
    key_a: 1
    key_b: 2
    key_c: 3
```

and convert the searched items to lowercase too. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: d2[item|lower]
      loop: "{{ test }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => (item=key_A) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  d2[item|lower]: '1'
  item: key_A
ok: [test_01] => (item=kEY_b) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  d2[item|lower]: '2'
  item: kEY_b
ok: [test_01] => (item=key_x) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  d2[item|lower]: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
  item: key_x
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    test: [key_A, kEY_b, key_x]
    d1:
      key_a: 1
      KEY_B: 2
      kEy_C: 3

    d2: "{{ dict(d1.keys()|map('lower')|
                 zip(d1.values())) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: d2

    - debug:
        var: d2[item|lower]
      loop: "{{ test }}"
```